# How to run .net Core IHosted Service at specific time Of the day?

Tags: c#, .net-core, timer, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am having the following Timer to run in .Net core Ihosted Service,

```
TimeSpan ScheduledTimespan;
string[] formats = { @"hh\:mm\:ss", "hh\\:mm" };
string strTime = Startup.Configuration["AppSettings:JobStartTime"].ToString();
var success = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(strTime, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ScheduledTimespan);
Timer _timer = new Timer(JobToRun, null, TimeSpan.Zero, ScheduledTimespan);
```

I'm using this specific overload,

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);
```

But `JobToRun` is executing as soon as the control reached to it.
How do I make it run at a specific time of the day on an everyday basis?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at scheduling components like Coravel ?

Comment: No. I haven't. I'll look for it.

Comment: @Aravind Thanks for your suggestion. I got the slution

Comment: You can add your answer to the question .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following function returns parsed job run time

```
private static TimeSpan getScheduledParsedTime()
{
     string[] formats = { @"hh\:mm\:ss", "hh\\:mm" };
     string jobStartTime = "07:10";
     TimeSpan.TryParseExact(jobStartTime, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TimeSpan ScheduledTimespan);
     return ScheduledTimespan;
}
```

Following function returns the delay time from current time of the day.
If current time of the day passed the job run time, appropriate delay will be added to job run like below,

```
private static TimeSpan getJobRunDelay()
{
    TimeSpan scheduledParsedTime = getScheduledParsedTime();
    TimeSpan curentTimeOftheDay = TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm"));
    TimeSpan delayTime = scheduledParsedTime >= curentTimeOftheDay
        ? scheduledParsedTime - curentTimeOftheDay     // Initial Run, when ETA is within 24 hours
        : new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0) - curentTimeOftheDay + scheduledParsedTime;   // For every other subsequent runs
    return delayTime;
}
```

use following overhead to achieve 24 hour delay after every execuion,

```
_timer = new Timer(methodToExecute, null, getJobRunDelay(), new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
```

timer will call the `methodToExecute` based on `JobRunDelay` everyday

Comment: Hi, Is it okay for you to update the entire service class. My service is not working as expected, unable to figure out. Will just cross with your service class.